Implement a Monad
A monad is a type that wraps another type, that represents the available operations on the wrapped type. Monads have the following associated operations, where M is the monad type, and T and U are any type:

A type constructor that defines a new type M[T] that can hold some type T.
A type converter that wraps a value and returns an instance of the monad: unit: (T) -> M[T]
A combinator that unwraps the monad instance, performs a provided operation on the contained value, then returns the wrapped result: bind: (M[T], (T) → M[U]) → M[U]

These operations have the following properties, given some function f and g, and a value x, where <-> is equivalence:

unit is a left-identity for bind: bind(unit(x), f) <-> f(x)
unit is a right-identity for bind: bind(x, unit) <-> x
bind is associative: bind(x, lambda a: bind(f(a),g)) <-> bind(bind(x, f), g)

Your goal is to write the shortest three functions, code snippets, and/or full programs that implements the above three operations. You must indicate which function/code snippet/program is which operation, as well as show the three properties of unit and bind above.
Note: If your language does not have the ability to declare a new type, you may instead replace your type constructor with an explanation on how your monad is represented in your language.
Note: You may use built-ins, but trivial substitutions, such as preprocessor directives (e.g. C++ #define M std::optional) or type aliases (e.g. Rust type M<T>=Option<T>), are not allowed. Solutions without built-ins are highly encouraged.
Note: Identity monads, single-valued monads, and other similar trivial monads are allowed; the challenge is to implement any one specific monad. However, you will get brownie points if your monad is able to wrap any valid type in your language.

"you will get brownie points if your monad is able to wrap any valid type in your language" - Is this not a necessary condition for M to be a type constructor (with the constraint that such a type must be well-kinded)?

You say there should be 3 separate programs, but since the unit and return programs will have to depend on the type-constructor-definition program for type information (except in silly cases), is it ok to specify all three things in one program?

@pxeger Yes, that's fine. I do say 3 separate programs, but they can be also 3 functions, code snippets, programs, etc. in any combination. That's what I meant with the and/or

@pxeger People in the sandbox asked whether trivial monads were valid submissions; for this challenge they are, but I would also like to see non-trivial monads.

I think the appeal of [tag:open-ended-function] challenges is that deciding which function is golfiest to implement is an interesting puzzle in itself.  But having mathematically trivial options available, like the identity monad and single-valid monad, makes for a boring choice that produces boring golfs. Just encouraging solvers to choose interesting non-built-in monads makes it more a popularity contest to "do a cool thing". I think a better challenge would ask to implement a specific monad.

Does the Monad have to work for all types T, or may we place restrictions on T (like T being a Monoid for example)?

@corvus_192 That would be fine, but ideally it should work with all types.

Haskell, 22 bytes
data M t=R t
R x%f=f x

Attempt This Online!
First, a definitely-correct answer. This is the identity monad: the type constructor is called M, the unit constructor is called R, and the bind combinator is called (%).
I defined a Monad instance in the footer to demonstrate that the operations have the correct types. I hope it's clear why the monad laws hold.

Pure Haskell, 12 bytes
data M t
z=z

Attempt This Online!
By "pure" I mean with no exceptions and no unsafePerformIO etc.
Highly debatable, but I think it's technically valid. My type constructor is called M (the resulting type just happens to have no values), my unit constructor is called z, and my bind combinator is also called z. Here's my proof of the monad laws:

We must prove z(z(x), f) <-> f(x). If f has type a -> M b for some a and b, then since there are no values of type M b, f must never return (and since we're in "pure" Haskell, f must be a simple infinite loop). Likewise z(z(x), f) will never return because z will enter an infinite loop, so the two expressions are equivalent.

We must prove z(x, z) <-> x. Similarly to the above, x has the type M a for some a, which means evaluating x will never return. Equally, z(x, z) will never return, so they're equivalent.

Very similar.



Pure, halting Haskell, 22 bytes
data M t=R
r _=R
_%_=R

Attempt This Online!
Another silly one. This requires that f has no side effects and always halts.

In fact, since not taking input at all is a valid standard I/O method, you could just have this:
Pure, halting Haskell, 10 bytes
data M t=R

Attempt This Online!
Here, my type constructor is called M, my unit constructor is called R (just make sure not to pass it any arguments), and my bind combinator is also called R (also no need to pass the arguments).

If I can argue this "I/O method" is allowed for the 3rd monad, maybe you can argue that this alone is valid for the 2nd monad? unit and bind take input by... not being called at all?
data M t


There's probably room for some more silly-but-valid Monads. But here's a non-trivial one - the Option monad:
Haskell, 30 bytes
data M t=N|R t
N%_=N
R t%f=f t

The unit constructor is called R, and the bind combinator is called (%).
Attempt This Online!

C++20 (gcc), 60 bytes
template<class T>struct M{T t;auto b(auto f){return f(t);}};

Where M is the monad, which allows types to be constructed by instantiating the template:
using Type = M<int>;

Values can be wrapped by using the converting constructor which is generated by the compiler automatically:
auto value = Type{42};

Although thanks to template argument deduction it's also possible to just write auto value = M{42}. And binding works by calling the member function b():
auto value_squared = value.b([](auto x){ return M{x * x}; });

Try it online! (Except at the time of writing, TIO is using an old version of GCC that doesn't fully support C++20 yet.)

OCaml, 37 bytes
type 'a m=M;;let u x=M;;let b x f=M;;

This implements a single-valued monad with constructor u and bind operation b.
And for an example of a non-trivial monad, let's see Reader<int> monad in 53 bytes:
type 'a m=int->'a;;let u x _=x;;let b x f s=f(x s)s;;


Javascript, 1 byte
0

This monad is isomorphic to Identity (). All values of the monad are 0.
The expression 0 defines a "function" with zero arguments (as in Haskell) that works as both unit and bind. As pxeger noted, this bends our rules very much, but I think it's still fun to think about, so I posted this.
